# Bluetooth not working properly?

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

When i turn on the bluetooth no settings or options are available.
What should i do?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall bluetooth
```

and then elevate to SU

```
sudo su
service bluetooth restart
```

Comment: E: Command line option --purge is not understood in combination with the other options